# SQL check if all values of bool are true by group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just new to sql and recently face an issue...

When in the order all the items are `IsRepInbound = True` then all the line items of this order will be `R`.
If in the order there is at least 1 item `IsRepInbound = False` then all the line items of this order will be `E`.

Tried Group By, but it seems i do not need aggregation... maybe OVER clause to Partition By?  Any hint?

**Table A**

```
"Item_Number"   "Order Number"  "IsRepInbound"
1                   OR-1            TRUE  
2                   OR-1            TRUE  
3                   OR-1            FALSE  
4                   OR-1            TRUE  
1                   OR-2            TRUE  
2                   OR-2            TRUE  
3                   OR-2            TRUE
```

**Table B (try to reach):**

```
"Item_Number"   "Order Number"  "Exchage_Ind"
1                   OR-1            E  
2                   OR-1            E  
3                   OR-1            E  
4                   OR-1            E  
1                   OR-2            R  
2                   OR-2            R  
3                   OR-2            R
```

Comment: What query did you use?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  In your post are you describing the desired behavior or the current/undesired behavior?  Can you post your SQL code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as @Tim Biegeleisen but with windows functions

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/IOGE73156)**

```
SELECT [Item_Number], 
       [Order_Number],
       CASE WHEN
               COUNT(CASE WHEN [IsRepInbound] = 'FALSE' THEN 1 END) 
               OVER (PARTITION BY [Order_Number]) = 0
            THEN 'R'
            ELSE 'E'
       END            
FROM Table1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Perfect Juan! I test from my side, it works by using partitiion by

Comment: And by using partition by is much easier than combination of group by and join.

Answer (score 1):

If a given item number has `TRUE` for all its values, then you want to report `R` as the result, but if it even has one `FALSE` then you want to report `E`.  You can use conditional aggregation by item number and tally each one to determine its label.

```
SELECT t2.[Item_Number],
       t2.[Order Number]
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [Item_Number],
           CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN [Order Number] <> 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
                THEN 'R'
                ELSE 'E'
           END AS [Order Number]
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY [Item_Number]
) t2
    ON t1.[Item_Number] = t2.[Item_Number]
```

Comment: maybe `COUNT` is more clear on these cases, because you are counting how many `false` are there. And you wont need the `ELSE` part

Comment: Thanks Tim! Your solution also works. By using partiton can also provide same logic. Anyway, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Use **Case statement**:

```
SELECT 
    Item_Number,
    Order_Number,
    CASE IsRepInbound 
      WHEN 'TRUE' THEN 'E'
      ELSE 'R'
   END AS Exchage_Ind  
FROM TABLE_A;
```

Comment: If one order is `FALSE` all order with same `ID` become `E` not just the `FALSE` one

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using Cross Apply

```
Declare @YourTable TABLE(Item_Number int, Order_Number varchar(4), IsRepInbound varchar(5))
Insert into @YourTable values
    (1, 'OR-1', 'TRUE'),
    (2, 'OR-1', 'TRUE'),
    (3, 'OR-1', 'FALSE'),
    (4, 'OR-1', 'TRUE'),
    (1, 'OR-2', 'TRUE'),
    (2, 'OR-2', 'TRUE'),
    (3, 'OR-2', 'TRUE')

Select Item_Number
      ,Order_Number
      ,B.Exchage_Ind
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select Exchage_Ind=case when min(IsRepInbound)='False' then 'E' else 'R' end 
               From  @YourTable 
               where Order_Number=A.Order_Number
              ) B
```

Returns

```
Item_Number Order_Number    Exchage_Ind
1           OR-1            E
2           OR-1            E
3           OR-1            E
4           OR-1            E
1           OR-2            R
2           OR-2            R
3           OR-2            R
```

Comment: did you realize your output doesnt match OP desire output?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for the catch!  Corrected.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the query as,

```
SELECT Item_Number,CASE
  WHEN ORDER = 'TRUE' THEN 'E'
  WHEN ORDER = 'FALSE' THEN 'R'
  END AS Order_Number, IsRepInbound as Exchage_Ind  
FROM TABLE_A;
```

Hope it gives you the result

Comment: If one order is `FALSE` all order with same ID become `E` not just the `FALSE` one